# How to send error logs on email in Scrapy

Tags: python, email, logging, smtp, scrapy

I want to send emails with errors, if they occur while Scrapy is working. I've added email handler and connect it to spider.logger:

```
def __init__(self, test=False, *args, **kwargs):
    eh = SMTPHandler('localhost', fromaddr='crawler@example.com',
                     toaddrs=LOG_EMAIL_LIST, subject='Error report')
    eh.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    self.logger.logger.addHandler(eh)
    super(BaseGenericSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I add errors manually (e. g. `self.logger.error('Test')`), I receive a notification on my email. But When I  test it with scrapy errors (e. g. I've made syntax typo in a crawler's code to test it), I see that Scrapy logged that error, but I didn't receive anything in my email. Can you help? Thank you in advance.

UPD.
Ok, I think I've found a problem, but I don't know how to solve it now. When I add a handler to `self.logger`, I have messages like this:

```
2016-02-12 14:23:19 [sslv] ERROR: Test error case
```

But scrapy errors have this format:

```
2016-02-12 14:44:28 [scrapy] ERROR: Error while obtaining start requests
```

So, as you see, scrapy logger has another name. Actually, also we have `twisted` logger and many other. How to set email handler to all of that's loggers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alreasy solved. I've add handler in `__init__.py` file and connect it to root logger.

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler

from settings import LOG_EMAIL_LIST

eh = SMTPHandler('localhost', fromaddr='crawler@example.com',
                         toaddrs=LOG_EMAIL_LIST, subject='Error report')
eh.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(eh)
```